# Joomla - adding custom button in article list at each article

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm new to Joomla.

I need to add "Export" button to administrator article list.

I would like to know how to add this button at each article on the list, then how to add action to make this export working - especially how to get article entity in "export" action, with all related info (category, tags).

Of course it should be a module or plugin, not in core joomla so after joomla update it will be working.

Please direct me into some tutorial or other webpages where it will be explained.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an "Export" button to the Article view would require a bit of work, so for the exporting side of things, I'd simply suggest you use a pre-built extension, such as [J2XML](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/j2xml) or [HexData](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/articles-import-export).

For more choices, have a look at the [Data Import & Export](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export) category on the Joomla Extensions Directory.

Comment: This export functionality have to export article to the other cms (written in ZendFramework 2), and from there I'm going to make push notification for the mobile users of app which data is stored in ZF2 CMS. So I have to make somekind of automatic article sending and running push queue on the other server (written in ZF2).
I dont know how will I make it - probably I will send articles through JSON REST Client. Thats why I need functionallity to push button at article row - run some PHP code to send data through http client. I need to have article content, its category, language and tags.

Comment: Ah ok, you should have mentioned this before in your question. Overall, what you're asking for is way too much and you're not going to find an extensions that does all this for you. You will most likely have to write your own plugin.

Comment: Ok. So should it be plugin? Or module or component? How to insert in plugin extra button in article list at each article? And how to implement this button functionality? I looked for answers but i have found only how to add burton in toolbar - not in article list. If i would knew how to implement this operation i will write my own code in php. Rest would be easy. Only thing i want to know is how to add this button, how to add action for this button and how to get article entity inside this action.

Comment: It should be a plugin. I would suggest you write a basic "blank" plugin and try to implement the button on your own. Then come back when you have a specific coding related issue. We're here to help with what you've already tried, not write your code for you ;)